# Redirect to custom 404 page correctly in apache?

Tags: php, apache

I want to have a custom 404 page on my apache web-server, therefore I edited the config file of the site and entered this line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for all cases. If the user enters something like `http://mywebsite.com/ldsakjfdalkj`, it works fine. But if the user enters something like `http://mywebsite.com/adf/adf/df/a`, I have a lot of problems with my paths. For example, in the second case, the 404.php looks up the background file in `./adf/adf/df/a/images/background.jpg` and the URL in my browser stays the same. Is there a way to properly redirect to `http://mywebsite.com/404.php`?

Comment: have you tried setting the path to the full url? e.g. `ErrorDocument 404  http://mywebsite.com/404.php`

Comment: Nope. I tried it and it works. Although this wouldn't be a very nice solution because my web-server is reachable from different domains. How can I solve this properly?